# Are the ships only different in appearance?

Tags: goscurry

There appear to be six unlockable ships.  They don't have any tooltips or anything, so I'm thinking maybe their just for aesthetics?

Do the different ships behave any different from one another?

[image: Ship Selection]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the ships are indeed different only in appearance. Except the PSYCHO (a tooltip should appear if you go over it), which will make every mode harder but also more rewarding.